# What are the Jordan curve theorems for higher genus surfaces?

Tags: general-topology, plane-curves, low-dimensional-topology

What are the Jordan curve theorems for higher genus surfaces?
I'm thinking of something like a surface with n handles can be represented as a 2(n+1) sided polygon Q with opposite sides identified.
Let C be a "closed" non-self-intersecting curve from a point p on one side to the "point on the opposite side" identified with p. Then Q \ C is `` topologically equivalent" to a 2k sided polygon with opposite sides identified where k<n+1.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a curve from $p$ on one side to $p$ on the opposite side -- if a surface is oriented, then the curve will remain on the "same side" of the surface the whole time.  In any case, there are two types of curves, those that separate and those that don't.  $Q\setminus C$ for non-separating curves (like one that wraps through the hole of a torus) all give a genus $n-1$ surface with two disks removed. Separating curves give two surfaces, each with a disk removed, with genus $a$ and $b$ where $a+b=n$.

Comment: @KyleMiller  By side I mean edge basically envision  the surface as a 2(n+1) sided polygon   so for a torus which is envisioned as a square with "edges" [0,1] x {1}, [0,1] x {0} and {1} x [0,1],  {0} x [0,1]  I consider a curve f:[0,1] -> surface starting at " (p,0) " and ending at "(q,1)"  that is the second coordinate $f(t)_2$ of f(t) is not 0 (or 1) for 0<t<1    for all  $\epsilon>0$  $\exists \delta$ $f(t)_2 < \epsilon  $ if $t < \epsilon$ and $f(t)_2 > 1-\epsilon$ for $t>1- \delta$

Answer (score 2):

Your question is ambiguous, but here are some examples of what's true:

Suppose that $S$ is a (possibly non-orientable) connected surface (without boundary) and $\alpha\subset S$ is a subset homeomorphic to $S^1$ (a Jordan curve). Then $S'=S\setminus \alpha$ is either connected or consists of exactly two components.

If, additionally, one assumes that $S$ is compact, then one can also prove that there are only finitely many homeomorphism types of surfaces $S'$ above.  If $\alpha$ is non-separating then there is precisely one homeomorphism type of $S'$. (The possible types depend on the topology of $S$.)

Proofs of such results are long. Consider reading for instance

*Farb, Benson; Margalit, Dan*, A primer on mapping class groups, Princeton Mathematical Series. Princeton, NJ: Princeton University Press (ISBN 978-0-691-14794-9/hbk; 978-1-400-83904-9/ebook). xiv, 492 p. (2011). [ZBL1245.57002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1245.57002).

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to prove is that if   $S'= S \backslash \alpha $ is connected, then it has smaller genus.

Comment: @HaoS: This is true only if $S$ is closed. A hint: use additivity of the Euler characteristic.

Comment: Don't really know topology what do you mean by additivity of Euler characteristic?

Comment: @HaoS: I suggest you modify your post to reflect what your real question is. The additivity formula is that $\chi(S')=\chi(S)$ in this case. If $\alpha$ is separating, splitting $S$ in $S', S''$, then the additivity means $\chi(S)=\chi(S')+ \chi(S'')$.